# Array of strings showing only the last string

Tags: c, arrays, char

I have some code that gets all the chars from a string received from a socket (connection is fine, not including variables connected to that). As you can see, in the preprocessing string `log_res_str` I assign to my array of strings `logins`, everything is fine. But when I print out the respective logins, it only shows the second one. What's the problem?

```
int logincount = 2;
char login_buff[CHUNK_SIZE] = {0};
char *logins[100];
char log_res_str[CHUNK_SIZE] = {0};
for(int i = 0; i < logincount; i++)
{
    int lenf = 0;
    int received = 0;
    memset(login_buff, 0, sizeof(login_buff));

    // the length of the UID stored in the first byte
    if((received = recv(client_sock, login_buff, CHUNK_SIZE, 0)) < 0)
        DIE("Receive Error");

    // getting the lenght of the login
    lenf = login_buff[0] - '0';
    for(int count = 1; count < lenf; count++)
        log_res_str[count-1] = login_buff[count];

    printf("log_res_str: %s\n", log_res_str);
    logins[i] = log_res_str;

    printf("login: %s\n", logins[i]);

    // acknowledgment
    if(send(client_sock, login_buff, sizeof(login_buff), 0) < 0)
        DIE("Acknowledge Error");
}
```

This is what I get:

```
log_res_str: root
log_res_str: _warmd
login: _warmd
login: _warmd
```

This is what I want:

```
og_res_str: root
log_res_str: _warmd
login: root
login: _warmd
```

Comment: `logins[i] = log_res_str` stores a pointer to the `log_res_str` buffer, not the string itself. If you want a copy of the string you'd have to allocate memory for the copy, then copy (with either `malloc` + `strcpy` or `strdup`).

Comment: @SleuthEye could you put it to an answer? that worked, I'd like to accept your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `logins[i] = log_res_str` stores a pointer to the `log_res_str` buffer, not the string itself.

If you want a copy of the string you'd have to allocate memory for the copy, then copy the string. If the string is null-terminated you could do this with either [`malloc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) followed by [`strcpy`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html):

```
logins[i] = malloc(lenf);
strcpy(logins, log_res_str);
```

or simply [`strdup`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html):

```
logins[i] = strdup(log_res_str);
```

If on the other hand the input string in `log_res_str` isn't null-terminated (or at least not guaranteed to be), then you should use [`memcpy`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html) for the copy:

```
logins[i] = malloc(lenf+1); // +1 if you want a null-terminated copy
logins[i][lenf] = '\0';     // this line only if you allocated +1 above
memcpy(logins, log_res_str, lenf);
```